# Problem in accessing AWS instance EC2 when Deploying angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, remote-server, aws-code-deploy

I have a project going on. The app already deployed on AWS. I updated the git with last version of code and now I want to update the server. I tried to use remote explorer on vs code and installed key-pair file (The installed as .cer) and I opened config file for ssh and filled the info for the server like:

```
Host server
   HostName: ip
   User: ec2-user
   IdentityFile ~/ssh/key-pair.cer
```

Now, when I try to login to host, it gives me the error:
Could not establish connection to "qserver": Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged the question with AWS CodeDeploy, I'm assuming that you do intend to use  CodeDeploy to deploy your app to EC2, which is definitely the better alternative to deploying it manually on the host via SSH login.

If you're following the steps from the [CodeDeploy documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-ec2-configure.html), you'll realize that you don't need to login at all manually to the target server. Instead, CodeDeploy uses an agent to retrieve the build artifact and deploys it on the host.

Typically you'd do that as part of a CI/CD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline. [Here's a tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html) that walks you through the complete process. Note that you can use GitHub instead of CodeCommit, or Jenkins instead of CodeBuild if you want, so the pipeline is flexible in terms of components that are used within.